# Timer task only works when phone awake

Tags: android

I have an activity, called from an alarm broadcast receiver, which plays a notification sound every N seconds. This is achieved with the following code:

```
repeating_notification_sound_timer.schedule(ring_the_buzzer_task, 0, 1000 * N);
```

Early on in the onCreate function of the activity I have the following code:

```
pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
            wakeLock.acquire();
```

This all works perfectly well, so long as the phone was awake at the point when the alarm is triggered. However if the phone was asleep the notification sound gets played exactly once and never again. The program does not crash or report any errors. Its as if the repeating_notification_sound_timer could only be bothered to work once! Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here is the code that sets the alarm in the first place:

```
static void set_alarm(long alarm_time_in_millis,Context cont,AlarmManager alarm_manager,String str)
{
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(cont, to_call_when_alarm_goes_off.class);

    launchIntent.putExtra("string_passed_in_bundle", str);

    launchIntent.setAction(to_call_when_alarm_goes_off.CUSTOM_INTENT);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont,0, launchIntent, 0);
    alarm_manager.cancel(pIntent);

    alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time_in_millis, pIntent);
}
```

**EDIT:** In the manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Comment: you need to read the documentation : "*If you hold a partial wakelock, the CPU will continue to run, irrespective of any timers and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wakelocks, the CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button."

Comment: @njzk2: what should my wake locking code look like then?

Comment: the doc seems pretty straight forward : if you want the cpu to run and hence your timer to be executed, you need a partial wakelock

Comment: Questions, 1. Does the phone go back to sleep, 2. Does the timer keep running but no sound is played or timer is fully stopped.

Comment: I just tried a partial wake lock, but then I never hear any alarm at all, the screen just remains black :-(

Comment: @Jug6ernaut: with the full_wakelock - the bell rings once, I see my UI correctly, but the bell does not repeat, but my UI remains visible forever (my phone is set to stay awake if plugged in to USB and not set to sleep manually).

Comment: & the timer? What is its behavior?

Comment: @Jug6ernaut: can you be more specific?

Comment: is the timer going off(its executing every x seconds) and the sound just isnt playing, or is the timer not running at all.

Comment: The timer appears not to be running. I have log statements next to the bell ringing code and I'm only seeing them the once.

Comment: It seems that w/e thread your timer is being created in is dying, i would suggest from you Receiver starting an IntentService which then starts your activity, or try starting your timer in a new thread, or using a Handler instead of a timer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your AlarmManager alarm to be of the wakeup veriaty, else the broadcast will wait to fire until your phone is wake up by something else.

Ether [RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP)

or [ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP)

For specifics please provide your alarm code.

Comment: See edit. But note that the alarm is triggered, and my activity is being called - the notification sound is being played - the problem is that it only gets played once.

Comment: Then you probably have a wakelock issue then, do you have the required permissions for the wakelock? Have you checked logcat at time of alarm going off?

Comment: See edit to OP. I have monitored the logs, but can't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to have something that keeps track of timing over a long period of time or while the app is in the background you really need to use a Service.

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand... My main application sets an alarm... after that, the application can be closed, the phone can be rebooted - all sorts. Only when the alarm triggers a broadcast receiver is called which creates an intent and my activity is executed for the first time. The activity will then ring every few seconds until the user presses a big button marked "stop".

Comment: He means that for a background task you really want to use a Service, not an Activity.
Activities are here for the parts of your app that have an UI.
Services are here to let you create background actions.

Comment: This activity does not run in the background, and it does have a UI - a big button with the word stop.

Comment: Right, but you need the app to keep working even when the application has gone into the background.  For that to happen you need to have a Service running.  You can use the UI to communicate to the Service and then have the Service manage all of the timing.

Comment: As long as his Activity aquires a valid wakelock there is no need for a service. The only background task (afaict) is the alarm that needs to go off, besides that everything else is to be run in the foreground.

Comment: Exactly, but his question asked why it wasn't working when the phone went to sleep.  The answer is that he isn't running a service.

Comment: Well even if he had a service that wouldn't make a difference if he didn't have a wakelock. Services get suspended all the same when the phone goes to sleep.